# Flutter : How to select image from a list

Tags: flutter, image, select, stepper

I'm stuck on a small point, I'm developing a self-help service application and I take care of creating the form to create an announcement.

For that I thought it a great idea to set it up as a Cupertino Stepper, but when I want the user to choose an image from a list I give, I don't know how to make an image selectable. Here is a picture of what I have so far (left) and what I would like (right):

Comparison between what I have and what I want

[image: 1]

And here is the code of the page I have:

```
    return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Stepper(
          currentStep: currentStep,
          onStepTapped: (index) {
            setState(() => currentStep = index);
          },
          onStepContinue: () {
            if (currentStep != 3) {
              setState (() => currentStep++);
            }
          },
          onStepCancel: () {
            if (currentStep != 0) {
              setState (() => currentStep--);
            }
          },

          steps: [
            Step(
                isActive: currentStep >= 0,
                title: Text('Choisissez une catégorie'),
                content: CupertinoPageScaffold(
                  child: DefaultTextStyle(
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: CupertinoColors.label.resolveFrom(context),
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        const Text('Catégorie séléctionnée : ', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                        CupertinoButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          // Display a CupertinoPicker with list of fruits.
                          onPressed: () => _showDialog(
                            CupertinoPicker(
                              magnification: 1.22,
                              squeeze: 1.2,
                              useMagnifier: true,
                              itemExtent: _kItemExtent,
                              onSelectedItemChanged: (int selectedItem) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedCategorie = selectedItem;
                                });
                              },
                              children:
                              List<Widget>.generate(_CategorieNames.length, (int index) {
                                return Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    _CategorieNames[index],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                          // This displays the selected fruit name.
                          child: Text(
                            _CategorieNames[_selectedCategorie],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Step(
                isActive: currentStep >= 1,
                title: Text("Choisir le titre de l'annonce"),
                content: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: TextField(
                    maxLength: 20,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                        ),
                        labelText: "Titre de l'annonce"
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Step(
                isActive: currentStep >= 2,
                title: Text('Ajouter une description'),
                content: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: TextField(
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLines: null,
                    maxLength: 250,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1.5),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                        ),
                        labelText: "Description de l'annonce"
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),
            Step(
              isActive: currentStep >= 3,
              title: Text('Ajouter une image'),
              content: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child:
                    Image.asset("images/Jardinage.png"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child:
                    Image.asset("images/baby sitting.png"),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child:
                    Image.asset("images/Coiffure.png"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: wrap your Image with `GestureDetector` then add `onTap` function , also wrap with `Container` to add border when image selcted

Answer (score 2):

You can make the image selectable by adding GestureDetector and changing the _selectedImageIndex using setState on each tap.

```
 Step(
           isActive: currentStep >= 3,
              title: const Text('Ajouter une image'),
              content: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedImage = 0;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 3,
                                    color: _selectedImage == 0
                                        ? Colors.green
                                        : Colors.transparent)),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/provinces/1.png"))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedImage = 1;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 3,
                                    color: _selectedImage == 1
                                        ? Colors.green
                                        : Colors.transparent)),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/provinces/2.png"))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedImage = 2;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                    width: 3,
                                    color: _selectedImage == 2
                                        ? Colors.green
                                        : Colors.transparent)),
                            child: Image.asset(
                                "assets/images/provinces/3.png"))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Alternate Solution : You can refactor the image selector widget as well

The variables will be

```
var _selectedImageIndex = 0;
  final _images = [
    "assets/images/provinces/1.png",
    "assets/images/provinces/2.png",
    "assets/images/provinces/3.png",
  ];
```

SelectabImage widget will be

```
class SelectableImage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectableImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.isSelected,
    required this.imageAsset,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final bool isSelected;
  final String imageAsset;
  final void Function(String imageAsset) onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => onTap(imageAsset),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                  width: 3,
                  color: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.transparent)),
          child: Image.asset(imageAsset),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Step function will be reduced to

```
 Step(
                      isActive: currentStep >= 3,
                      title: const Text('Ajouter une image'),
                      content: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          for (int i = 0; i < _images.length; i++)
                            SelectableImage(
                              isSelected: _selectedImageIndex == i,
                              onTap: (selectedImageIndex) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedImageIndex = i;
                                });
                              },
                              imageAsset: _images[i],
                            ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
```